# Java Instrumentation finding object size

Tags: java, object, size, instrumentation

When calculating a Java object size

```java
Class Test { 

   private String name = null;

   private List<String> myList = null;

}
```

Is it true the size of the **Test** class object will be different if i have one item in the list compared to thousand items in the list?

Comment: Try it and see, using the instrumentation API that you refer to.

Comment: Not really, no.  The `Test` will be the same; it always contains only a _reference_ to a list that lives somewhere else in memory, and that reference always has the same size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that depends how you want to count it.

The `Test` instance itself won't be bigger, it just has a reference to a `List` instance (or `null`, but that also takes up the same amount of space), and that `List` instance is its own object stored elsewhere on the heap (*outside* of your `Test` instance).

The `List` instance will (depending on the implementation) also not vary in size, but it will in turn reference other objects (list entries, or arrays, or other things).

In general, all class instances in Java take up a fixed memory allocation that is determined by the class and does not vary from instance to instance. The only thing that can have a "dynamic" size are arrays (but it's not all that dynamic, as it also is fixed on array creation time, so it can vary from instance to instance, but not over time for a given instance)

If you want to calculate a "closure over the object graph" of all the memory needed for the `Test` object and all dependencies/contents (for example to estimate how much memory is needed to serialize it to a file), then yes, it would grow depending on how many objects are in the list.

Also note that an `ArrayList` with `["foo", "foo"]` might consume the same total amount of space as just `["foo", "foo", "foo"]` (because the same single string instance is re-used three times, and the backing array has eight entries anyway). Or you might have multiple `Test` instances sharing the same `List`. So it's not that easy, and depends on how you want to count.

Comment: Great explanation of all the subtle aspects of “what is an object’s size”, though calculating the actually occupied memory in a managed environment is even more complicated. Only one small remark, the default capacity of `ArrayList` is ten, not eight.